# Regex to validate password of specific criteria

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking forward to have a regx pattern to match following criteria:

Validate/require that field contains
Mixed case
  10 character minimum length
16 character max length
2 numerics are present (minimum)

2 alpha are present (minimum)

1 special character (minimum)

Allowed specials:  `!#.*`

Other special characters should be rejected

All characters must be non-consecutive

No repeats  e.g.   “alittle1A!”  would be invalid because it has “tt”

Any Help would be appreciated

so far i have developed:

```
var passwordPattern = /^(?=.*\d{2})(?=.*[a-z]{2,})(?=.*[A-Z]{2,})(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9]{2,})(!#.\*)\1?(?!\1).{10,16}$/;
```

this doesn't seem like working.

Comment: Does this kind of validation not occur on the back-end? If not, it really should. There's nothing stopping some JS-savvy user from just submitting the form and bypassing your validation. Also, is there a particular reason you can't allow any character in your password? You should be hashing and salting the password on the client-side before passing it to the server anyway, otherwise you're just inviting attacks.

Comment: Just FYI: by imposing some of these restrictions, the strength of the password is actually being weakened. Also… I feel very sorry for anyone who needs to write down the contrived password they will use in this system :(

Comment: Here's the only reason why you would enforce password restrictions: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/15355

Comment: @Adrian - best practice is to do it in both places.  The back-end does it for security reason (e.g., like you said, a hacker can get around the JS validation) and the front-end does it for a good user experience . . . it's simply not a good experience to force a user to sit through a server request and page reload to do format checks that you can do easily (and immediately) on the front-end.

Comment: @talemyn - The only way you can really do validation on the characters contained within a password, though, is to have access to the password in plaintext. At no point should the password be transmitted in plaintext over any connection, even a "secure" one. At no point should the password ever be stored in plaintext, either. That said, in case plaintext transmission is occurring, why not just use AJAX -- then you don't have to wait for a "page reload." You just have a little loading spinner, followed by an error message.

Comment: @Adrian - I believe he is talking about setting a password, not logging in with it.  In which case, you can use a `<input type="password">` element to mask the value, but still access it via the JS `value` or jQuery `val()` in order to do client-side validations.  All of those initial validations can be done on front-end, and then confirmed on the backend, once the value has been securely passed to the server.

Comment: @talemyn - My point is, if the password is being sent to the server as a salted hash, then there is no reason to restrict what characters it contains, because the only truly valid reason for restricting characters in a string is the charset encoding of the database in which the password is stored (if the password is stored as plaintext -- which it should not be). Min length is understandable. Max length is understandable. Only allowing `!` and `#` is silly.

Comment: @Adrian - I think we might be crossing topics here . . . seems like you are arguing against the password rules that he is suggesting . . . my comment was addressed to you very first one, where you were suggesting that there was no need for front-end password value validation.  While I agree that that should not be the final validation, as it is not secure, it is a much better experience to allow a user to correct as many validation issues as possible **before** passing the values to the server.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47899/discussion-between-adrian-and-talemyn)

Comment: Firewall at work blocks the chat functionality here.   :(

Comment: Oh, well in summary I agree that minlength and maxlength should probably be verified on the front-end. Anything else is irrelevant and should be a non-issue for a hashed-and-salted system.

Comment: I totally get what you are saying, but it makes a big assumption that he has control over the password rules that he is dealing with.  Could very well be that someone has told him that these are the rules that they want and it is simply his job to make them work.  Shoot, I had to develop a site that supported IE5.5 a couple of years back . . . you'd better believe that that wasn't my idea.   :D

Comment: If a user is smart enough to bypass javascript detection of how secure a password is, they are "smart" enough to deal with the consequences of such behavior.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto -- true, but why would you enforce the restrictions in the first place? It's relatively well-known that this doesn't actually make passwords more secure, and also leads to them being more difficult to remember. Furthermore, the only reason I can think of for why you would restrict the characters in a password would be if the database is storing it in plaintext and cannot support some characters due to a restrictive charset encoding, which means it's being stored in plaintext, which means that if someone hacks the database, everyone's passwords are instantly exposed and usable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex:

```
/^(?=(\D*\d){2})(?=([^a-z]*[a-z]){2})(?=[^!#.*]*[!#.*])(?!.*?(.)\1)[a-z0-9!#.*]{10,16}$/i
```

Comment: I would really recommend not validating password constraints on the client-side, except perhaps min-length. Any password with any complexity can be hashed and salted and sent to the server, and the server will not care what characters are in the password, because all it sees is a SHA or MD5 hash string.

Comment: You're missing this rule: `All characters must be non-consecutive`, but there really needs to be some more explanation of what that means . . . consecutive letters? Consecutive alphanumeric? Consecutive Unicode characters?

Comment: I thought I had it covered here: `(?!.*?(.)\1)`

Comment: That covers the `No repeats` rule . . . non-consecutive would be like no "12" or "ab".

Comment: Ah but `non-consecutive` with pure regex is near impossible.

Comment: Good one +1. But the question says: _"mixed case"_ so there may also be a requirement for both upper and lower case alphas. The question is not clear on this point.

Answer (score 2):

You should not restrict the characters allowed in a password, other than perhaps the min-length. There is nothing you can do to force a user to pick a secure password. All you can do is ensure you have a secure system that will not be weakened by a single compromised user account.

1. Never transmit unencrypted plaintext passwords
2. Never store plaintext passwords
3. Never send the user their existing password when they do the "I forgot my password" song and dance -- reset it and send them a one-time use password (still risky) or use a token system to allow them to log in by clicking a link, and ensure they are forced to set a new password upon login.

If you are following those rules, then there is no reason you can't use special characters -- hashed-and-salted passwords won't contain those characters anyway, so even data-type or charset restrictions are invalid reasons at that point.

Here are some related questions/answers about why what you're suggesting is not helpful and may actually be harmful:

1. [Why do modern websites still insist on archaic username/password requirements?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/219198/why-do-modern-websites-still-insist-on-archaic-username-password-requirements?rq=1)

   Summary: Doing this is completely arbitrary and has no effect on security
2. [Why do certain sites prevent spaces in passwords?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/126924/why-do-certain-sites-prevent-spaces-in-passwords)

   Summary: It amounts to the laziness of the programmer or uncertainty that the passwords will be stored in a secure fashion or handled correctly
3. [Are there any valid reasons for disallowing characters and limiting the length of passwords](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/87366/are-there-any-valid-reasons-for-disallowing-characters-and-limiting-the-length-o?rq=1)?

   Summary: limiting length can limit the hashing time
4. [Why do websites restrict the number/choice of characters in a password?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/15350/why-do-websites-restrict-the-number-choice-of-characters-in-a-password)

   Summary: lazy programmers
5. [Should you enforce password restrictions? (SitePoint)](http://www.sitepoint.com/should-you-enforce-password-restrictions/)

   Summary: password restrictions are supremely annoying

Here's a suggestion -- test some passwords that match your restrictions here:

https://howsecureismypassword.net/

Once you've done that, compare the "security" of those passwords with some following this style:

http://xkcd.com/936/

You might also wish to look into two-factor authentication (because in the end, even a secure password system isn't really secure):

https://www.twilio.com/blog/2013/04/add-two-factor-authentication-to-your-website-with-google-authenticator-and-twilio-sms.html